# Same JPA callback method in @MappedSuperclass and child class

Tags: jpa

Can I define same JPA callback method in parent and child class as below? If yes, do I need to invoke super.onPrePersist(); in child class onPrePersist() method?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @PrePersist
    protected onPrePersist() {
        System.out.println("Parent onPrePersist() invoked");
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child extends AbstractEntity {

    @PrePersist
    protected onPrePersist() {
        **super.onPrePersist();**
        System.out.println("Child onPrePersist() invoked");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you test it? JPA entities are Java objects, and obey the same rule. If you override a method, the overridden method will be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a unit test for the above scenario and It works. For each of the callback methods in child class, you have to invoke the parent callback method first:

```
@Override
@PrePersist
protected onPrePersist() {
    **super.onPrePersist();**
    System.out.println("Child onPrePersist() invoked");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to invoke the parent callback method by yourself, **just don't override the** `@PrePersist` **annotated method** as it hides the parent method and prevents it from being executed. If your callback methods have different names they will be invoked in the order according to their place in the hierarchy, most general classes first.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @PrePersist
    protected onPrePersistParent() {
        System.out.println("Parent onPrePersist() invoked");
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child extends AbstractEntity {

    @PrePersist
    protected onPrePersistChild() {
        System.out.println("Child onPrePersist() invoked");
    }
}
```

This will produce the output:

1. Parent onPrePersist() invoked
2. Child onPrePersist() invoked